# Z3 install error: datalog_frontend.cpp NMAKE : fatal error U1077 from Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: z3

I follow https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3
to install Z3. However, the error occurs after **nmake**.
I have tried either **python scripts/mk_make.py** or **python scripts/mk_make.py -x** to generate build folder but they all failed after nmake.

Is this a bug? How can I install Z3?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\z3-master\z3-master>cd build


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\z3-master\z3-master\build>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.22816.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

datalog_frontend.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(10): fa
tal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or director
y
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\z3-master\z3-master\build>
```

image link: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WWoy.jpg

Comment: I'm not familiar with Z3, but you might have better luck creating an issue on the github project.

Answer (score 0):

I (Bing) found this related question: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86bc577b-528c-469c-a506-15383a44c111/missing-corecrth-from-the-default-include-folder-for-vs215?forum=vcgeneral

I still use VS2013 to build Z3 and sometimes VS2015 for profiling, but one
thing you need to make sure of is to use a command-prompt that has all the required include directories on the path.
That is, my command prompt invokes:
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86